# Google Cloud PostgreSQL for QGIS

Tags: postgresql, google

Has anyone used Google PostgreSQL and added it as a data source?   I have 2 shapefiles that I need to work on with multiple concurrent users and be able to edit them "offline" and synchronize them when possible.

I am looking for a possible plug in or example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like if you use the [Google Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#proxy), you should be able to just add it as a regular postgresql datasource.